# What kind of culture would an undead nation develop?

Tags: magic, culture, fantasy-races

Imagine a high fantasy world where some powerful necromancy was developed. After a massive war, a few liches began raising undead from the bodies and souls of the fallen warriors using a lengthy ritual. These undead are intelligent, mentally independent, have some of the same drives as their original selves, but lack a memory of their past life. The undead have banded together into a small nation.

The typical undead citizen is a skeleton, although a few are ghosts or zombies. If properly trained they can become liches themselves, and can raise their own undead. This creates a sort of hierarchical family, with the lich as the head of an extended family.

What kind of culture would arise in this nation of undead? How would it be different from a kingdom of humans?

Comment: I think it could develop almost any culture you desire. A lot might be based on circumstances, and the main 'drives' might be crucial to determining the outcome. To sum it up, I'll explain it in terms of writing or pure worldbuilding - the result might simply be what you want it to be, as long as you keep being acceptably consistent in the long run.

Comment: You described a clan-based structure. Were I resurrected into a clan with a chief unworthy of my loyalty...and had to serve that same chief forever...I might consider it more akin to perpetual servitude.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it needs clarity.  groups form governments to meet their needs.  The question needs to posit the needs and wants of the Undead for there to be an answer that isn't opinion based

Comment: I think this is the basis for a really interesting worldbuilding query. Too bad it's gotten some answers, because now it can't be fixed.  I think if you were to refine your wording and spell out some constraints, you could have an interesting question on the very nature of unalive culture, as opposed to what elements an unalive culture might comprise.

Comment: @elemtilas - open to ideas how to fix the question. I thought it was pretty clear and it got some great answers so far. It is sad that "opinion-based" is over-used, especially for fictional world-building.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that these undead are the typical ones:  they do not age or die of old age.

As a consequence, the biggest cultural differences would be those in reproduction and inheritance.

Where do they get the bodies to create new members?  Are they on relatively civil terms with their neighbors and can trade for them?  Are they continually under attack, or conversely continually invading, and therefore can use the corpses from the battlefield?  Depending on how often new ones are created, this can be a major part of their culture, or a minimal one, far below the importance of raising children.

The only undead who need to be educated are the newly created ones, and these are created fully grown.  Education would be geared toward them, and given the concentration of their creation to near the parental liche, educational institutions would be severely localized.  A liche who created dead over a region would probably have specific outposts to do so, precisely so they can be outfitted to deal with new undead.

On the other hand, their immensely long "lives" let them learn many things a living being would have little time for.  You can learn how to weave in the manner of an ancient civilization from someone who actually learned it from the practitioners.  They may regard themselves as the truly civilized, the preservers of the knowledge of all ages.

Finally, there is no way up in the cultural hierarchy except through the violent death of your superiors or expansion.  If the vast majority of your undead are happy to "live out lives" of culture and knowledge and use, that can produce a stable society.  (Perhaps the odd-balls are sent out to adventure and get themselves "killed.")  If any sizable number are not happy, you have a society of intense internal violence (overt or covert) or an expansionist one.  How rapidly it expands depends on whether their long "lives" increase their patience.  A skeleton that knows in that a couple of millennia he can become the Supreme Emperor of the Delectable Islands can work more slowly than a human who will have at most thirty years to conquer -- but if the skeleton does not adjust to his undead timeframe, he may act as if he had decades.

Answer (score 3):

You can break down a culture into practical solutions to problems, and answers to humans questions.

Who we are, where do we come from, how to live life...etc.

The other aspect is to solve actual problems.
If it's too hot you develop architecture and technology so that you exist in the place, then with time so you can actually enjoy your time.

Like it's too cold outside, so we developed heating so we can enjoy an evening at home while it's freezing outside.

But if your skeleton does not feel the cold, would it need heating?

So you have to simply remove the vast majority of things in any human culture as it is a result, whether direct or not, of needs.

Obviously there is other layers.
For example a functional 2000$ car does the job of a 200000 car, but owning the expensive one has other benefits.
However neither would exist in the first place if the need to travel did not exist.

So to conclude I think you have one of two ways.
Create a clear and reasonable need or want for your dead.
And only after you have done that start thinking of how to develop a culture around it.
Like how a lot of human civilization started around fresh clean water, or how iron was an important resource, or how agriculture changed society...etc.

Like a magical resource that they can use.
This resource enables them to control more land or have more power or raise more dead...etc.
And thus around it grows all sorts of things.
Like if it's a crystal, then going around wearing robes made of super expensive crystals becomes a symbol of power.

The second is much darker, and interesting.
Just have your dead emulate humans without the actual need or want.
Silk robes while they don't feel touch, expensive rings but they don't see color, comfortable beds but they don't even sleep, super exotic meals they can't even consume...etc.
So the whole society is a bit of joke as they pile and pile more expensive and rare stuff that means nothing to them in a mockery of their humans selves or in in an inescapable pit of consumerism even after death.

That's how I see it anyway